How to remove Device infon plus
nvalid depfile: D:\Coding\Flutter\Freelance Work\fincyn\fincyn.dart_tool\flutter_build\706fdf46efec99c7a1309b7efac7f1ca\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: D:\Coding\Flutter\Freelance Work\fincyn\fincyn.dart_tool\flutter_build\706fdf46efec99c7a1309b7efac7f1ca\kernel_snapshot.d
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':device_info_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


error: invalid source release: 17

cant remove this dependendependency

have you tried flutter clean; flutter pub get; flutter build apk in same sequence?

Downgrade the package to
device_info_plus: 9.1.2
will solve this
